# How to recover errors when submitting with formik

Tags: reactjs, formik

I have a Formik form like this :

```
              <Formik
                    initialValues={createUser}
                    onSubmit={handleSubmit}
                    validationSchema={Schema}
                    validateOnChange={false}
                >
```

and I'd like to retrieve the form value (isValid) and any errors when I click on the onSubmit button but the handleSubmit function only retrieves the values and the FormikHelpers.

```
   const handleSubmit = (values: any, formikHelpers: FormikHelpers<any>) => {
    console.log('formikHelpers', formikHelpers);
   };
```

does anyone have a solution for recovering values in Formik?